# How to disable page load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, svg

I have a `SVG` animation on my website,which placed in the middle of page, and when i enter to my website, page loading, and `SVG` animation automatically draw the image, so how can i do that `SVG` animation load when i scroll down?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){ 

        document.onreadystatechange = () => {

            if (document.readyState === 'complete') {

                /**
                * Setup your Lazy Line element.
                * see README file for more settings
                */

                let el = document.querySelector('#case');

                let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":4.6,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#2ECC70","strokeCap":"square","delay":320}); 
                myAnimation.paint();

                let el1 = document.querySelector('#clients');

                let myAnimation1 = new LazyLinePainter(el1, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":2.6,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#2ECC70","strokeCap":"square","delay":210});

                myAnimation1.paint();
            }
        }

    })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load it within scroll event handler when user scrolls down

```
// jquery solution
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (lastScrollTop != 'loaded' && st > lastScrollTop){
            let el = document.querySelector('#case');

            let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":4.6,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#2ECC70","strokeCap":"square","delay":320}); 
            myAnimation.paint();

            let el1 = document.querySelector('#clients');

            let myAnimation1 = new LazyLinePainter(el1, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":2.6,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#2ECC70","strokeCap":"square","delay":210});

            myAnimation1.paint();
   }
   lastScrollTop = 'loaded';
});
```

This should start loading the svg first time user scrolls down on your page.

Comment: Sorry if i ask u witless question, which class i must to put in this code?

Comment: @Bieksa I've edited my answer, actually It seems that you don't even need ajax for this. Just move your code to scroll event handler